# Rails best practice to create method on sql query in model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a method in model based on the sql query below

```
SELECT TOP 1 Column1
FROM vSomeView
WHERE vSomeView.ColumnID = @column_id
AND Column2 = 'Abc'
AND Column3 = 'Def'
```

I created the method for this but want to know what is the best practice to have conditions in where. should all where conditions be in scope or they should be in method?

```
class Abc
  class Def < ActiveRecord::Base

self.table_name = 'vSomeView'

scope :column2scope, -> { where(column2: 'Abc') }
scope :column3scope, -> { where(column3: 'Def') }

def self.some_method(column_id)
  Def
    .select('vSomeView.column1')
    .where("vSomeView.ColumnID = #{column_id}")
    .first
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the scopes like:

```
scope :column2scope, -> { where(column2: 'Abc') }
```

can be used independently. ie would it be useful to call Klass.column2scope to get all matching records? A real example would be something like:

```
scope :expired, -> { where('created_at < ?', 1.year.ago) }
```

Now we can call Product.expired to find old products. Or combine it in a query Product.expired.where(department: :food).

If the query is always the whole thing together, you may as well just put it together in a method.